# How to spin only the changed digits in a number picker

Tags: android, numberpicker

I am developing an application in which I use a `NumberPicker`. 
The only issue is that I want to spin only the changed digits.
For example :
- if I want to spin from 123 to 124 only the last digit will move (3 -> 4)
- if I want to spin from 3479 to 3480 the last 2 digits will move (79 -> 80)
Is there a way to do that without using a picker for every digit?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: unfortunately it seems that you need to build custom picker, or try to find an open source equivalent for that.

Comment: Why can't you use just one `NumberPicker` in order to get a single digit? You can have the number 123 as a whole number and after you spin it once, you'll get either 122 or 124 (only the last one will move and if you change 3479 to 3480 the last two will move. I don't get the idea behing having a separate `NumberPicker` for each digit? Thanks

Comment: @g00dy if you want to spin the number 123 to 124, all three digits will move up, even though only the last one will change. i want the ones that do not change on a spin cicle to not move.

Comment: @cosmincalistru - then I could suggest you to use the `NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener` - more info here (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener.html). You can put those on any of the `NumberPickers` so that if the old value is 9 and the new one is 0, you change the adjacent `NumberPicker`, which will also have a listener for the same thing. You just have to figure out what to do if you have just 3 `NumberPickers` and you get to 999. I think that this is a think that could be easily implemented.

Comment: I forgot to add, that the same goes for the decreasing value, so this clause should also be added (going lower than zero, which should decrease the counter to the left). Also if the "whole `NumberPicker`" supports negative numbers, this should also be taken into account.

Comment: can you explaint what you want , sorry I cant understand it,

Comment: I'd advise to create a numberpicker for each digit you want the user to be able to select, then do some magic in the back to read the values or add/remove numberpickers when needed ie 99->100 and 999->1000

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use these Third party libraries instead of androidx NumberPicker if you want:

https://mindorks.com/android/store/Number-Pickers/chils17/odometerlibrary

https://github.com/alexzaitsev/meter-number-picker